# Can someone explain what why this code is wrong?

Tags: ios, swift2

```
var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
```

The error message i get says call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled.

also I have this line of code

```
if ((error == nil && captureSession?.canAddInput(input)) != nil)
```

> Optional type 'Bool' cannot be used as a boolean; test for "!=nil" instead.

Auto Correct is on but for the second line when i click fix it just rewrites the same line of code and adds another "!=nil".

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error that says

> this call can throw, but it is not marked with `try` and the error is not handled.

because you did not catch the exceptions that could be thrown. Instead, you should be using this

```
var error: NSError?

do{
    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
}
catch let myError as NSError{
    error = myError
}
```

The second error is because `captureSession?.canAddInput(input)` returns an optional `Bool` value. To fix this, you should be using `(captureSession?.canAddInput(input) ?? false)`, which effectively turns `nil` values into `false`.

```
if(error == nil && (captureSession?.canAddInput(input) ?? false))
```

A better way to do this would be to put it all in the do-catch statement

```
do{
    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)

    if((captureSession?.canAddInput(input) ?? false)){
        //your code
    }
}
catch var error as NSError{
    //handle the NSError 'error'
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding that syntax and it caused more errors than originally with those 2 lines

Comment: @ReggieS. What do the errors say, and with which line are they?

Comment: I messed with it and the error switched to two other lines now. Its another if statement. it says use of unresolved identifier "error" and "input" in the same line. In the next line it says the same thing for "input". should if statements be "do". Im a beginner

Comment: @ReggieS. Maybe I should have been more clear - those are *generic* variables - you should replace them with your variables

Answer (score 0):

For your first line, I believe all you have to do is surround it with a

```
do{
   try //statement
}catch {

}
```

For the second statement, I believe the reason why the compiler is complaining is because you are trying to evaluate a type Bool for nil or not, try simply having

```
(error == nil && captureSession?.canAddInput(input))
```